# How to extend a Generic class and return a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have a generic class

```
public class PagedData<T> where T : class
{
        public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalRowCount { get; set; }
        public int RowsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
}
```

I am going to extend the above class as shown below

```
public static PagedData<T> PagedResult<T>(this List<T> list)
{
     //some logic and return result as type PagedData<T>
     return null;
}
```

But it shows one buld error like

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'T' in the generic type or method 'MyApplication.PagedData'

Please let me know one solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the class `PagedData<T>` has a constraint on the type parameter `T`, you have to explicitly replicate that constraint on your own method:

```
public static PagedData<T> PagedResult<T>(this List<T> list) where T : class
{
     //some logic and return result as type PagedData<T>
     return null;
}
```

If you don't do this, it would be "possible" to call `PagedResult<int>` but then it would be impossible for it to return a `PagedData<int>` -- which is why the compiler complains.